# Simplest way to setup a failover web server

Tags: php, web-server, haproxy, failover

So I have a simple web app (LAMP) , minus (MySQL) , that stores user generated data into files (think photos, audio etc). I want to setup a failover webserver  what's the easiest way to do this?

Thinking about using a cron to just rsync data files to backup  server , but need some way to detect when primary server is offline and point to new web server. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancer with heath check in front of the web servers.